# Adding default external network in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to learn docker and understanding docker-compose

As I was trying out the external network section:

```
 networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network
```

I understand that 
'my-pre-existing-network' needs to be created.

Is it possible to create a new default external network from within the compose file itself?

This is more from a learning/understanding perspective. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible , it is called `external` because is created from outside the current `docker-compose.yml` you are working on